# A list of event types that d3js supports

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using `d3.js` to create a data vis tool. I read in d3 documentation that event listener can be registered using `selection.on(type[, listener[, capture]])` API. As it is documented here:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on

However, I cannot find a list of event types that d3 supports. Now I know there are `'click'` event, `'mouseover'` event and `'mouseout'` event. What else does it support?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably every DOM event.

Comment: How can I write them? What I need is just a list. I tried to search on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event , but it does not give me any clue on how to write event types in d3js.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events

Comment: Your answer is quite enough for me. But I'll accept the more formal and detailed answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

D3 supports any Javascript event in the `on` method -- including custom events created by other code.

The MDN [Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events) is a good list of types of events that will be created by the browser.

Pay attention to which types of DOM objects can respond to which types of events, though.  The element within the d3 selection has to receive the event for the D3 `on` method to be able to react to it.

Also be aware that for some complex types of user interaction, like dragging, it is easier to use a [d3 behavior object](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Behaviors), which monitors multiple system events, both mouse movements and touch screen movements, and creates custom events that you can then react to.

Comment: Also, be sure to check the compatibility tables on MDN.  Not all the events in that list work the same in every browser.